# Find the order of a point on a elliptic curve over a finite field

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, cryptography

**Context** Alice and Bob want to communicate using the Diffie–Hellman-ElGamal system based on the elliptic curve E over $GF_{11}$ given by the equation $y^2 = x^3 + 2x + 5$, with the point $P = (0, 4)$. Bob decided to have $sB = 2$ as his private key. By experimenting in the group $(E, +)$, Alice found out that $5P = (4, 0)$.

(a) Using the above information, show that the order of P in the group $(E, +)$ is equal to $10$.
Hint: determine first the order of the point $(4, 0)$ by working out its inverse in $(E, +)$.

There are more questions regarding the actual encryption, but I think I can do those on my own.

**My attempt** I know the inverse of a point is the same with a change of sign on the y-coordinate. So my guess is $5P = (4, 0) = (4, - 0) = -5P$, then $5P + 5P = 10P =$ (point representing infinity). This means the order is 10?  I'm not very confident in this answer.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Oh dear, nice catch.

Comment: The inverse of a point is not always the same as change of sign on the $y$-coordinate - you need short Weierstrass form. But here it seems correct to me.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've never heard of short Weierstrass form before and the wikipedia for Weierstrass's elliptic functions seems quite intimidating.  Would you mind explaining in general terms what it is?

Comment: I just found a post on here by none other than yourself from 2014 answering my question so thanks for that contribution.  Is it not in a $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ form already?  Sorry if I've misunderstood.

Comment: You're right that $10P = 0$. So the order divides 10...